# Addition or scaling of Random Variables with other r.v. or an scalar.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

See the page-$74$ in the book [Schaum's Outline of Probability by Seymour Lipchuz](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/schaums-probability.pdf).

> If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables on the same sample space $S$, then $X+Y$, $X+k$, $kX$ and $XY$ (where $k$ is a real number) are the functions on $S$ defined by
>
> $\bullet$ $(X + Y)(s) = X(s) + Y(s)$
>   $\bullet$ $(X + k)(s) = X(s) + k$
>   $\bullet$ $(kX)(s) = kX(s)$
>   $\bullet$ $(XY)(s) = X(s)Y(3)$
>   for every $s \in S$.
>
> It can be shown that these are also random variables. (This is trivial in the case that every subset of $S$ is an event.)

I need some examples of these 4 identities using a die-roll example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't really what I'd call "identities;" they're definitions.  It's just saying that e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables representing dice rolls then the meaning of the "+" sign is that we roll the dice and add the numbers together.

Comment: still not clear. In that case, we can say it joint r.v.s, not addition or scaling of r.v.s

Comment: Rolling two dice and adding the results together does not give you the joint distribution of the two rolls.  If I tell you I rolled two dice add the total was 7 you don't know if I rolled a 2 and 5 or a 4 and 3 or a 5 and 2 or what.